# Is the [ethics] tag appropriate?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-cleanup-request

[ethics](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ethics) is an undefined tag.  It has two questions, both closed.  Comments on both go to the issue of whether ethics is an appropriate topic for this site.  I would think the existence of the tag would attract off-topic questions.  Should this tag be eliminated?

Answer (score 3):

Those two questions are gone now.